# Where does python under conda look for a package?

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, conda

I am trying to manually install a python3.8 module under conda. My module is a python wrapper of [a C++ library](https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/blob/master/python_orocos_kdl/INSTALL.md). It comes with CMakeLists.txt. By specifying `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to miniconda3 directory, I achieve that the corresponding .so module appears in `miniconda3/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/`.

Then, I run python in the same terminal and I can successfully import the module. But if I open another terminal, then the module cannot be found.

I have checked that both terminals run the same python (`which python`), and have identical environment (by comparing `printenv` outputs). I also have checked that `sys.path` values are identical and include  `miniconda3/lib/python3.8/`. Still, the behavior is different.

So where does python look for modules?

The official documentation says that `sys.path` is the place, but it seems not the only place.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as to not confuse anyone who might encounter this same issue. The only thing I will point out from the discussion is, that it is weird that one terminal is able to open up the module while the other one isn't.

I would recommend trying out running the script that imports the module from the same directory as the module `.py` itself. And see if that fixes it. Python scans for `.py` modules using `sys.path` and IIRC the **current working directory** (and/or the same directory as the script)

Comment: Thanks! That was a silly mistake of me, I indeed run python in one terminal in the same directory I built the package, and it doesn't run from any other. The only thing still not clear is that `lib/python3.8` is in sys.path, and `lib/python3.8/dist-packages` contains the copy of `.so` file. Why python recognizes this file in the current dir (build) and does not in the `lib` dir?

Comment: I think you will have to address that question to the developers of python. My wild guess is that it's due to the age old argument of white-listing vs black-listing, i.e. white-listing is generally safer than black-listing (meaning that if you specify the exact directory then it's much less likely to be vulnerable to some forms of attacks). But that's just a wild guess. Great news that it's fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is most likely not related to the current problem.

Try running **this command** in your terminal before you open up `python`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
```

This isn't python looking for `.so` files, but rather `ld` (linker).

EDIT: The issue stemmed from different **working directories** in the used terminal windows. Python searches within `sys.path` and `cwd` (current working directory) for imported modules. More in the discussion under the question.

Comment: This doesn't work. As I mentioned, I confirmed that the environment is identical for two sessions.

Comment: @alvis Post the complete error then, the only other thing that might prevent the module from loading (that I can think off without any error messages) are file permissions.

Comment: @alvis Also a quick question: Did you run `ldconfig` ? Note this might require you to edit: `/etc/ld.so.conf` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html

Comment: There is a standard error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyKDL'

Comment: Running ldconfig didn't change the result, but thanks for the note.

Comment: @alvis One more thing that I can think off. If I'm not mistaken python also searches the current working directory for modules. Can you run the script that imports `PyKDL` from within the directory where the `.so` file is located? Perhaps even move the script there, just to see what happens? It's really weird that one terminal is able to run it and the other isn't.